# Can I view websites on an iPad in an iPhone sized window?

Tags: iphone, ipad, web-browsing, display

I'm trying to test out how my website looks on the iPhone, but all I have is an iPad. Is there a way to force the iPad into iPhone size view window?

Comment: I recommend http://crossbrowsertesting.com/ for this.  You can test with various iOS versions as well.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can't do that. But if you have a Mac, you can install Xcode from the Mac App Store for free.

It comes with an app called iOS Simulator which will let you run Mobile Safari on your Mac, including the resolution of older iPhones/iPods (non-retina display), new retina display iPhones, and the iPad's resolution.

It also implements all the touch screen Javascript events (eg: onmouseover is triggered when you tap instead of onclick, then onclick is triggered when you tap again), double tap to zoom into a DOM element, and will properly show you how things like fixed position CSS elements will appear, which is very different on Mobile Safari compared to regular desktop Safari, and it gives you all the iOS form elements (`<select multiple>` fields are completely different for example).

I'm not aware of any way to properly test your website on Windows or Linux, changing the browser window size is not good enough.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you have to be a developer to do this?

Comment: Nope, you only need to be a developer to deploy apps on the App Store and access beta versions of OS X. All of the tools have always been freely available from Apple, ever since the 80's.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could find a third-party browser app that is only for the iPhone and use that on your iPad.  There are plenty of free ones.  Just search for "browser" in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

More or less any browser which has a special iPhone version (not universal) will work. I recommend the [Perfect Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/perfect-browser-extraordinary/id317836614?mt=8), or [Aquari](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/aquari-stealth-browser/id297443759?mt=8) iPhone browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dolphin browser. Just download it for iPad from iPhone apps section. You can also use service like http://testiphone.com

Comment: this shows the page, but you can't scroll :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a desktop version of Google Chrome, it can emulate an iPhone.  In the debug mode, click the "emulate devices" icon near of top left of the debug panel, and it can let you emulate iPhones, iPad, Samsung phones, and many other models (the list is about 20 items long).

It not only emulate the width and height, but it will act according to your `meta` tag for `viewport` as well.  So if you have this line in your HTML `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Then the emulator for iPhone 6 Plus will show a "yes I am a small screen and I will act accordingly" version of the page.  On the other hand, without the above line, iPhone 6 Plus will pretend itself to be a powerful browser with a wide screen, and show you the page -- but in this case the text will be very small and not very readable.  So what I mean is, Google Chrome will emulate your phone with the HTML code being displayed faithfully, as if it is a real device.

Compare that with Firefox version 44.0, which can only emulate the device size, but it won't care about the `meta` line above, so you could see one version of the page on Firefox, and see a different version of the page on a real device.

Here is a screenshot of emulating an iPhone 6 Plus:

[image]

Comment: It's a good answer but it's not emulating an iOS device in the strictest meaning of the word - it's simply emulating the dimensions of an iOS device.